# Nested exception is not correctly reported in the ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring

In a rest application, i create a class to manage error

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ProcessPaymentException.class)
    private ResponseEntity < String > handleProcessPaymentException(ProcessPaymentException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    private ResponseEntity < String > defaultExceptionHandler(Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }
```

}

In my service layer

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void processPayment(Long paymentId, PaymentModeEnum paymentMode) throws ProcessPaymentException {
    processCreditCardPayment(paymentId, paymentMode); 
}

private void processCreditCardPayment(Long paymentId, PaymentModeEnum paymentMode) throws ProcessPaymentException {
    try{
       chargePayment(paymentId)
    }catch(ProcessPaymentException ppe){
        throw new ProcessPaymentException(ppe.getMessage()); #1
    }

}

private ResolverReceipt chargeMemberCreditCard(Long paymentId, PaymentGatewayConfig paymentGateway) throws ProcessPaymentException {

   ...
   if(memberId==null){
       throw new ProcessPaymentException("error process payment");#2
   } 
}
```

When i get a `ProcessPaymentException`, i see in debug mode, when i go in the `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, i pass by `defaultExceptionHandler`.
I don't understand why, i was thinking to pass  `handleProcessPaymentException` method.

The debug message i see is:

```
Target object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null.
e= (org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException) org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Target object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null
```

I was thinking to get: `error process payment`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.asyncdev.net/2011/12/spring-restful-controllers-and-error-handling/) article, if you have used custom resolver, you need to define following lines to use @ExceptionHandler.

```
@Component
public class AnnotatedExceptionResolver extends AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver
{
    public AnnotatedExceptionResolver() {
        setOrder(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```